# Como validar tags tr em uma tabela com React

Tags: javascript, validação, react

Eu possuo dois componentes. O primeiro é o pai e o segundo é renderizado no pai como tags tr, como linhas em uma tabela, as mesmas precisam de validação. Pois as tags tds contem inputs que precisam ser validados antes do pai gravar as informações deles(essa parte ainda não foi implementada). Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso usando React? Como validar vários componentes filhos?
Segue o código do componente pai:
Vou omitir algumas partes do código no geral para facilitar a visualização

```
import React from "react";
import  ComboAjax  from "../Componentes/ComboAjax/comboAjax";
import  Row  from "../Componentes/Table/Row";
import  RowVazia  from "../Componentes/Table/RowVazia";
import { webServiceUrl } from "../constants/web-service";
import { authHeader } from "../helpers/headerAutenticacao";



class Timesheet extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            rows: [],
            rowsNovas: ['row']
        } 

        this.leituraSolicitacao = this.leituraSolicitacao.bind(this);
        this.inserRowNova = this.inserRowNova.bind(this);
    }
    leituraSolicitacao() {
        fetch(webServiceUrl + '/solicitacoes/' + localStorage.getItem("id") + "/201804", authHeader("POST"))
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } 
        }).then(resposta => {
            this.setState({
                rows: resposta
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Erro na leitura de solicitacoes.")
        })
    }

    inserRowNova() {
        this.setState((prevState, index) => ({    
            rowsNovas: [...prevState + 'row' + index]
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.leituraSolicitacao();
    }


    render() {
        return(
                    <tbody id="tbody_timesheet">

                        { 
                            this.state.rowsNovas.map((index) => {
                                return(
                                    <RowVazia key={index}/>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>

    )}
}

export default Timesheet
```

Segue o código do componente que é renderizado no map do componente pai:

```
import React from "react";
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask';
import ComboAjax from "../ComboAjax/comboAjax";
import { validaData } from "../../helpers/validaData";

class RowVazia extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
           valorBotaoControle: 'SOLJAVA',
           idInputData: Math.random()
        }

        this.trocaControle = this.trocaControle.bind(this);
        this.validaData = this.validaData.bind(this);
    }

    trocaControle() {
        switch (this.state.valorBotaoControle) {
            case "SOLJAVA":
                this.setState({
                    valorBotaoControle: 'SOLMESTRA'
                })
                break;
            case "SOLMESTRA":
                this.setState({
                    valorBotaoControle: 'NÃO POSSUI'
                })
                break;    
            default:
                this.setState({
                    valorBotaoControle: 'SOLJAVA'
                })
                break;
        }
    }

    validaData() {
       validaData(this.state.idInputData)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <InputMask style={{fontSize: '13px'}} onBlur={() => this.validaData(this.state.idInputData)}  className="form-control" id={this.state.idInputData} mask="99/99/9999">
                    </InputMask>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button style={{fontSize: '13px'}} onClick={() => this.trocaControle()} className="btn btn-info btn-md btn-block"
                    value={this.state.valorBotaoControle}>{this.state.valorBotaoControle}</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <InputMask mask="9999/99-99999" className="form-control">
                    </InputMask>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ComboAjax url="/projetos" valorId="id" nomeObjeto="descricao" classe="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <InputMask maxLength="60" className="form-control" >
                    </InputMask>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <InputMask maskChar="99:99" className="form-control">
                    </InputMask>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.validaData} className="btn btn-danger">
                        <span className="icon icon-bin2"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

}

export default RowVazia;
```

Comment: Qual tipo de validação ? Não consegui entender.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, não importa qual exatamente. Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de implentar isso de qualquer forma, validar se todos os campos de uma linha em uma tabela são válidos por exemplo